# How to avoid line breaks in PowerShell inline documentation

Tags: powershell

When I add the following documentation to a PowerShell function:

```
.PARAMETER Test
The test parameter is nice
and it looks pretty cool.
```

I get this help when I use the `Get-Help FunctionName -Parameter Test` command:

```
-Test <Object>
    The test parameter is nice
    and it looks pretty cool.
```

I want it to be:

```
-Test <Object>
    The test parameter is nice and it looks pretty cool.
```

How can I avoid the line break?

I want the line breaks in my source code because long lines are hard to read. The sample has a short paragraph but my real inline documentation does have long paragraphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any other option than writing it in one line. If you have long lines try to break them after 80 characters or so.

Comment: So you pretty much have to do the formatting your self. It is a shame, someone should file a bug.

Comment: Here's the official page to file bugs/suggestions: http://connect.microsoft.com/powershell

Comment: This is hard to deal with in the inline help.  MAML help seems to be the only way to get good formatting.